# Plotting points in Maple

Tags: maple

I want to plot a single [2,-2,0] in Maple.
I am trying to use command:

> pointplot3d([2, -2, 0], axes=normal, symbol=cross)

it does not work(maybe because pointplot3d is for a list of points). Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked for me, provided that I either invoked it as `plots:-pointplot3d(...)` , or `plots[pointplot3d](...)` , or as `pointplot3d(...)` only after having loaded the plots package by `with(plots)`.

The default color and size may not be to your liking. Here's a screenshot (Maple 15.01, Windows 7),

```
plots[pointplot3d]([[2, -2, 0]], axes=normal,
                symbolsize=20, symbol=cross, color=red);
```

[image]

You mentioned about its being a single point. Wel, in all of Maple 13.02, 14.01, 15.01, and 16.00 it also works as `plots[pointplot3d]([[2, -2, 0]],...)` which is a list of lists.

Comment: it worked thanks. I downloaded the with(plots) package and then used my input pointplot3d([2, -2, 0], axes = normal, symbol = cross).
If I wanna plot points my way do I have to load wit(plots) every time?

Comment: You'll have to load the package once per session (or after restart), if you want to use the "short form" of the command names. But you don't have to call with() before every subsequent, separate call to commands in the package. Just once, up front.